# Room migration fails without error

Tags: error-handling, kotlin, android-room

i'm working with Room and suddenly it stops to show errors when i changed one or more entities. For example i add one field (vendor: String) to my Entity and it just clear all data without any error or suggestions. Just clearing all data and stop working. I don't use fallbackToDestructiveMigration.

Please help i really don't know how to avoid this. All of my branches wait for db sync.

Here is the code

```
@Database(entities = [(ServiceEntity::class), (ConfigEntity::class), (RequestEntity::class), (FaqEntity::class),
    (SubscriptionEntity::class), (OrderEntity::class), (DeviceEntity::class), (ProblemEntity::class)], version = 5,
        exportSchema = true)
abstract class RoomAppDataSource: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun serviceDao(): ServiceDao
    abstract fun configDao(): ConfigDao
    abstract fun requestDao(): RequestDao
    abstract fun otherDao(): OtherDao
    abstract fun subscriptionsDao(): SubscriptionsDao
    abstract fun ordersDao(): OrdersDao

    companion object {
        private val TAG = RoomAppDataSource::class.java.simpleName

        private val Migration_4_5 = object: Migration(4, 5) {
            override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ${RoomContract.TABLE_SERVICES} ADD COLUMN vendor TEXT default '' NOT NULL")
            }
        }

        fun buildDataSource(context: Context): RoomAppDataSource = Room.databaseBuilder(
                context.applicationContext, RoomAppDataSource::class.java, RoomContract.DATABASE_APP)
                .addMigrations(Migration_4_5)
                .build()
    }
}
```

P.S. If i remove new line it works fine, but when i add smth in any entity app starts from tutorial page, because there are no tokens saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. I don't know why, but room just stop asserting new version of db or destructive migrations, so error i can see only when use Dao funcs. May be it will help to someone.